# R Transpose Row to column, Reshape group the column . How to expand it

Tags: r

Hi I have been trying to transpose the data which have the structure like below;

```
ID Seq PRODUCT  
A1  1     A
A1  2     B
A1  3     C
A1  4     D
A1  5     E
A2  1     C
A2  2     D
A2  3     E
A2  4     F
A3  1     A
A3  2     C
A3  3     D
```

and  I need the new structure like this

```
ID   1   2   3   4   5
A1   A   B   C   D   E
A2   C   D   E   F
A3   A   C   D
```

I have tried this code, but the output is still incorrect.

```
dt <- reshape(mydata,  v.names = "Seq" ,timevar = "Seq", direction = "wide", idvar = "ID")
```

Recently I have tested

```
reshape(mydata,  ,timevar = "Seq", direction = "wide", idvar = "ID")
```

but it seemed like my actual data have long "Seq", so the data is grouped in to a single column like below. How to expand the column? My actual data have maximum sequence around 30 sequences.

```
ID PROD 1:5 
A1 NA
A2 NA
A3 NA
```

Comment: `library(tidyr); df %>% group_by(ID) %>% spread(Seq, PRODUCT)`

Comment: You just want `reshape(mydata, idvar="ID", timevar="Seq", direction="wide")`

Comment: Your only real mistake was you should have specified `v.names = "PRODUCT"` as the variable you wanted to convert from long to wide. By specifying `"Seq"` instead, you ending up converting the same variable used to define the times into long format, and left `PRODUCT` to be considered a constant value in each group.

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried reshape(mydata, idvar="ID", timevar="Seq", direction="wide") , but it seems like my Seq are pity long so they a grouped in a single column. How can I expand my column

Comment: Thanks so much I have already solved my problem . Data Table seems to be more efficient. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253517/8057588